# When USB keyboard is plugged in on computer start-up, search results window is being opened multiple times

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

When my Alienware keyboard is plugged into my laptop during Windows 7 resume from sleep/hibernation, the windows search results and help window (F3, F1 on Windows 7) is being opened multiple times.

This behavior won't stop until I pull out one of the two USB connectors this keyboard has. When I plug it back, everything is normal.
Also, if I only connect one of the two during Windows resume, it won't happen.

Do you have any idea what could cause this weird issue?

**Edit**: Following the feedback on comments suggesting to log my keypress'es during the weird behavior, I've noticed it's actually **F1**, **F2**, **F3** being spammed in an ordered sequence. Clicking on them manually didn't stop them from repeating.

Comment: I would try a different keyboard.  If that fails reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound: Are you kidding? It doesn't happen with other keyboards, because other keyboards connect only with one USB port. And reinstall Windows? A perfectly working setup?

Comment: @DvirAzulay If it was "perfectly working", you wouldn't have posted this question.  Have you tried the keyboard on other systems?

Comment: @Iszi: Yes, on my brother's desktop PC. Everything is fine there. I was referring to the suggestion to re-install windows over a small issue with a certain keyboard, which is blatantly wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it's Win+F? It could be F3. Try log your keypress

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo: I like the suggestion to log the keypress. I'll try it out and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo: I've logged the keypresses during this weird behavior, and it's F1, F2, F3 all pressed in an ordered sequence, over and over again. Clicking them myself while this happens doesn't stop them from repeating it. I'll update the question with this info

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after a sleep wake-up on Windows 7.  Finally fixed it by changing power settings.
Control Panel, hardware and sound, Power options, Edit plan settings, change advanced power settings.
usb settings, 
Set usb selective suspend setting :Disabled